# Adding Pop-Ups to vector tiles layers (ArcGIS Online)

Tags: arcgis-online, popup, vector-tiles

I've been trying to get Pop-Ups to work on a published vector tile layer, but can't seem to get them to work.

I followed this help document - https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/help/data/services/use-vector-tiled-layers.htm - specifically the portion under "Enable pop-ups using an associated web feature layer" but don't get the option to "Set Pop-up Source" when I right click the vector tile layer under contents.

I've published the a feature class layer online to my content, but I can't get to the point of setting the pop-up source to the vector tile layer as I can't even find this option anywhere.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in the map viewer in ArcGIS Online?

Comment: Yes, within the contents pane in the map viewer of ArcGIS Online.

Comment: The link you posted is only for ArcGIS Pro. The map viewer in ArcGIS Online currently does not support popups on vector tile layers but it is something we are planning on adding.

Comment: @RussRoberts is this added yet? Thanks